# PreventDefault does not work for on with delegation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write some JQuery so that whenever the user clicks on a link (i.e. the `a` tag), there's an alert, and the link does not actually jump to another place.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(document.body).on('click',"a",function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Hello!"); 
    });  
});
```

The links in this file are not actually in the HTML code, but rather they are inserted by some other JavaScript. The alert works, but the default is not prevented. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another event handler bound on those elements ? And that you're running the right code ?

Comment: Alright, can you make a fiddle replicating this problem?

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/SZ7pW/

Comment: I use this on the href when I don't want it to Navigate : `href="javascript:void(0);"` I am not sure if this what you need.

Comment: 1) I'm sure I'm running the right code 2) I think I don't have another event handler bound on those elements, but since the codebase is so large and I didn't write most of it, is there a way to check? 3) The link is an internal link. (i.e. just jumps to a different part of the page) I don't know whether that caused the problem.

Comment: @MikaH. Please, could you try `alert($(this).prop('href'));` I am thinking that the href is not added by a JS function but rather handled with another event listener... And that event is fired before yours, so no way to prevent it.

Comment: @Salketer I tried what you suggested, and it alerted the URL that it's supposed to jump to, and then jumped to that URL.

Comment: What does `$._data( $("a")[0], "events" );` show in your console? This displays all the events bound by jQuery... Maybe we can find something there. Change the selector to point to a troublesome anchor as it points to the first on the page as it is.

Comment: @Salketer `console.log($._data( $("a")[0], "events" ));` shows "undefined"

Comment: @MikaH. Please, http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36957/mika-assist let's not flood the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to put an end to this question as troubleshooting happened in chat as it required too much back and forth...

Everyone was right, the code works perfectly. The problem OP had is that another code was adding an eventListener. This could not be tracked so only source file digging could make it appear. If the whole application uses jQuery, then jQuery knows all the events it has attached, so something similar to the troubleshooting proposed would show the events and then help to dig up the lines to add/remove: `$._data( $("a")[0], "events" );`

If, like the OP, you end up with codes you do not know that add vanilla (normal) JS events using addEventListener, there is no way to list the eventListeners of an element so debugging is not so easy. One small prototype hack can help you though, adding this code as the VERY FIRST js code to be executed by the page (just put it hard in a  tag):

```
var sourceAEL = Element.prototype.addEventListener;
Element.prototype.addEventListener = function(type, listener){
    console.log('Type: '+type);
    debug;//Will stop the code from executing allowing debugging in browser console (and thus know what calls it)
    sourceAEL.apply(this,[type,listener]);
};
```

Comment: +1 for detailed report, even if questions should not be solved in chat

Comment: @dystroy I do think so too. But this would have never been solved. Chat was to merely because I felt like helping out solve his specific problem. The question itself, if rephrased knowing what we now know, would still be too specific to be of any use.